# Three buttons in window form opening a same another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have three buttons in a window form to open 3 differnet forms, but these are opening same form which should be opened by `button1` only.

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task addnew = new Task();
        addnew.Show();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs h)
    {
        Task History = new Task();
        History.Show();
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs v)
    {
        Task Evaluate = new Task();
        Evaluate.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your form name are `Task` , `History` and `Evaluate` then Initialize your three from in three method

```
 public partial class Home : Form 
 { 
    public Home() 
    { 
      InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task addnew = new Task();
        addnew.Show();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs h)
    {
        History history = new History();
        history.Show();
     }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs v)
    {
        Evaluate evaluate = new Evaluate();
        evaluate.Show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: yes, better indentation now. So you're probably right.

Comment: @mostafizur rahman it worked, but i don't know how a form name can be used as a function name which i used to initialize my method.

Comment: its actually not method call when you are initializing using form name like method `Evaluate evaluate = new Evaluate();` it means you are calling that forms `constructor` for initialization, you can find a method name as same name as form name in every form this is `constructor` function called during initialization

Comment: for your `Home` form here is constructor function ` public Home(){InitializeComponent();}`

Comment: now it says that task does not contain a constructor, what it means ? Do i have to write constructor for every form to call them from my home form ?

Comment: by default every form have a default constructor like home form `public Home() 
    { 
      InitializeComponent(); 
    }` if not present then write like home form for each one

Comment: I have lost buttons from the home.design form.. they exist in home.cs file and project compiles successfully but the buttons are not showing after compiled. help me plz